# ion-fab-list on open, on close event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Hi I hope you can help me with this.

I´m using ionic 2 and I want to have control on the ion-fab this is the HTML structure:

```
<ion-fab left bottom>
  <button ion-fab mini>
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <button ion-fab (tap)="changeMap('SATELLITE')">
      <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
      <div class="label-map">Satellite</div>
    </button>
    <button ion-fab (tap)="changeMap('HYBRID')">
      <ion-icon name="map-map"></ion-icon>
      <div class="label-map">Hybrid</div>
    </button>
    <button ion-fab (tap)="changeMap('NONE')">
      <ion-icon name="map-map"> </ion-icon>
      <div class="label-map">None</div>
    </button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

What I want is to know when is the ion-fab-list opened and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Ionic does not provide an API to listen to those events, but you could easily add it like this:

```
<ion-fab left bottom> <!-- Bind the click event here -->
  <button (tap)="fabToggled()" ion-fab mini>
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <button ion-fab (tap)="changeMap('SATELLITE')">
      <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
      <div class="label-map">Satellite</div>
    </button>
    <button ion-fab (tap)="changeMap('HYBRID')">
      <ion-icon name="map-map"></ion-icon>
      <div class="label-map">Hybrid</div>
    </button>
    <button ion-fab (tap)="changeMap('NONE')">
      <ion-icon name="map-map"> </ion-icon>
      <div class="label-map">None</div>
    </button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

And then in your component code, add the following:

```
// It's closed by default
private isOpened: boolean = false;

public fabToggled(): void {
    this.isOpened = !this.isOpened;

    if(this.isOpened) {
        console.log('Opened...');
    } else {
        console.log('Closed...');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to put the function in the button ion-fab, because when I tap an ion-icon it fires the fabToggled function :)

Comment: how to detect when fab close by other click event. I click somewhere else fab will automatically close then how to detect at that time?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari could you please create a new question with some more details about your code? Thanks :)